# How do I import a picture in LaTeX?

Tags: diagrams, code, import, format

I am new to latex. I want to import a picture but failing.
The picture is .jpg format.

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX! Use `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package will do. // Also please provide a minimum working example (MWE) to show your error.

Comment: You must specify the engine you use to compile. The latex engine don't accept jpg pictures although pdflatex does.

Answer (score 4):

If `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex` is used to compile `.tex` file. You can use `graphicx` package to insert `.jpg` image file.

```
% pdflatex xelatex lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image.jpg}
\caption{title}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If you use `latex` to compile. I suggest you convert `.jpg` to `.eps`. [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) can help you to convert.

```shell
convert example-image.jpg example-image.eps
```

```
% latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image.eps}
\caption{title}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `.jpg` images must be taken into account by the compilation engine. `pdflatex` accepts them while `latex` refuses them.

Comment: @gigiair You are right. I have updated my answer.