# Import a picture in LaTeX?

Tags: external-files, import, picture-mode

I just started writing in LaTeX.
I want to import a picture but failing.
The picture is .png format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/672168/how-do-i-import-a-picture-in-latex

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? Then we could have a look what might be going wrong.

Comment: Thank you all, I only used \includegraphics without importing graphicx

Answer (score 0):

you can also import figure from specific url, for example:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\write18{wget http://www.some-site.com/path/to/image.png}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=40mm,height=40mm]{image.png}
\caption{\centering\label{fig:Fig1} This is figure's caption  }
\end{figure}
```